# Subtracting date

Tags: c#

How to do I subtract two dates and display days left?

`expire` (the expiry date) variable comes from the database.

```
expire = row.expire.ToString("dd. MMMM. yyyy");
dayleft = DateTime.Now.Subtract(expire).ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Subtract` method returns a TimeSpan, so you can do something like this:

```
DateTime expire = DateTime.Parse(row.expire);
TimeSpan difference = expire.Subtract(DateTime.Now);

double totalDaysLeft = difference.TotalDays; //eg. 3.69

int daysLeft = difference.Days; //eg. 3
```

Comment: It says  CS1061: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Subtract' and no extension method 'Subtract' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: So `row.expire` is a string? Then you need to convert it to a DateTime object first. I'll adjust my answer.